# Is fiware-skuld working within a federation?

Tags: fiware, fiware-skuld

I have a question about fiware-skuld.

Is It working Skuld within a federation? 
Must be use globally or in each FIWARE Lab region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to run individually Skuld on each region. There are some
serious problems:

- the users are global. The change of the user type (from Trial Users to Basic Users type) can be invoked only one time. The same is true for the notifications. Users do not want a
  notification for each region.
- there is a problem of synchronisation if each region delete their
  resources when they want. Users must be notified only one time and
  with a defined anticipation.

At this moment the scripts are invoked only for a region, but to support a
federation it is sufficient to modify only the scripts that delete resources to
iterate with each region.